# DeadObjectException with YouTubeThumbnailView

Tags: android, listview, android-youtube-api

I try to display a YouTubeThumbnailView in a Listview using the YouTube API, but no way to do this. I need to display a text and a video (or an image if there is no video) which requires a custom adapter and a YouTubeThumbnailView. I know there is some topic open about it but no way to fix it. (Everything works fine worthout YouTubeThumbnailView)

Here's the adapter code:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {
public static final String TAG = NewsAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;
private List<News> mListNews;
private Map<View, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> mLoaders;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> list) {
    this.mListNews = list;
    this.mContext  = context;
    this.mLoaders  = new HashMap<>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mListNews.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return this.mListNews.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = convertView;
    Holder viewHolder;
    String videoId = mListNews.get(position).youtube_code;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.item_news, null);
        viewHolder = new Holder(v);

        viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setTag(videoId);
        viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.initialize(BuildConfigData.getKEY_API(), this);

        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (Holder) v.getTag();
        // 2) and 3) The view is already created...
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = mLoaders.get(viewHolder.youTubePlayerView);
        // ...and is currently being initialized. We store the current videoId in the tag.
        if (loader == null) {
            viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setTag(videoId);
            // ...and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId on the loader.
        } else {
            viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setImageBitmap(null);
            loader.setVideo(videoId);
        }
    }

    if(this.mListNews.get(position).title != null) viewHolder.newsTitleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mListNews.get(position).title));
    viewHolder.newsCategoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(!this.mListNews.get(position).main_picture.isEmpty()) {
        final Holder finalview = viewHolder;

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
    String videoId = (String) youTubeThumbnailView.getTag();
    mLoaders.put(youTubeThumbnailView, youTubeThumbnailLoader);
    youTubeThumbnailView.setImageBitmap(null);
    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(videoId);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}



class Holder {
    ImageView newsImgImageView;
    TextView newsTitleTextView;
    TextView newsCategoryTextView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubePlayerView;

    public Holder(View base) {
        newsImgImageView     = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_img);
        newsTitleTextView    = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        newsCategoryTextView = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_category);
        youTubePlayerView    = (YouTubeThumbnailView) base.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_thumb);
    }
}
```

and here's the stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.p.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.a.setVideo(Unknown Source)
        at com.meetphone.fabvillesdk.adapter.NewsAdapter.getView(NewsAdapter.java:85)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4972)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4516)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.k$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need custom view (display video if exists or display image) I think may need to separate video view and image video with different `ViewHolder`

Replace your `getView` method into `listView` Adapter and create two separate `getVideoView` method for youtube Video view, `getImageView` method for image view

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    String videoId = mListNews.get(position).youtube_code
    if (videoId.isEmpty()) {

       return getVideoView(position, convertView, viewGroup);
    } else {
       return getVideoView(position, convertView, viewGroup);
    }
}

public View getVideoView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    VideoViewHolder viewHolder;


    if (convertView == null || (convertView != null && convertView.getTag() instanceof VideoViewHolder)) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.item_news, null);
        viewHolder  = new Holder(v);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (VideoViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setTag(videoId);
    viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.initialize(BuildConfigData.getKEY_API(), this);
    // 2) and 3) The view is already created...
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = mLoaders.get(viewHolder.youTubePlayerView);
    // ...and is currently being initialized. We store the current videoId in the tag.
    if (loader == null) {
        viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setTag(videoId);
        // ...and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId on the loader.
    } else {
        viewHolder.youTubePlayerView.setImageBitmap(null);
        loader.setVideo(videoId);
    }

    if(this.mListNews.get(position).title != null) {
        viewHolder.newsTitleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mListNews.get(position).title));
    } else {
        viewHolder.newsCategoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 

    return convertView;
}


public View getImageView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ImageViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null || (convertView != null && convertView.getTag() instanceof ImageViewHolder)) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.item_news, null);
        viewHolder = new Holder(v);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    if(this.mListNews.get(position).title != null) {
        viewHolder.newsTitleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mListNews.get(position).title));
    } else {
        viewHolder.newsCategoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 

    if(!this.mListNews.get(position).main_picture.isEmpty()) {
        final Holder finalview = viewHolder;

    return v;
}
```

modified your `Holder` class and create `VideoViewHolder` and `ImageViewHolder` classes

```
class Holder {
    ImageView newsImgImageView;
    TextView newsTitleTextView;
    TextView newsCategoryTextView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubePlayerView;

    public Holder(View base) {
        newsImgImageView     = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_img);
        newsTitleTextView    = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        newsCategoryTextView = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_category);
        youTubePlayerView    = (YouTubeThumbnailView) base.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_thumb);
    }
}

class VideoViewHolder extends Holder {
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubePlayerView;

    public Holder(View base) {
        super(base);
        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) base.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_thumb);
    }
}


class ImageViewHolder extends Holder {
    ImageView newsImgImageView;

    public Holder(View base) {
        super(base);
        newsImgImageView     = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.news_img);
    }
}
```